# get substring in php with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string like below

```
$string = '["{apple}","{mango}","[apple: red]", "[apple: green]","{pear}" ]';
```

I want to use preg replace so that my result looks like below

```
$string = '["{apple}","{mango}","apple:", "apple:","{pear}" ]';
```

So whenever there is square bracket I need to replace  it with just the text that contains colon at the end.

Comment: a "text" with a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you anything between a `"[` and the first `:`.

```
"\[(.+?):.*?\]"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lI9yE8/1

PHP Usage:

```
$string = '["{apple}","{mango}","[apple: red]", "[apple: green]","{pear}" ]';
echo preg_replace('/"\[(.+?:).*?\]"/', '"$1"', $string);
```

Output:

```
["{apple}","{mango}","apple":, "apple:","{pear}" ]
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/498076

In your example it is unclear why your second `"apple"` doesn't have the colon. If the found value shouldn't have the colon move the `:` outside the capture group. Your replacement string has both cases so it is unclear what you want.

So:

```
(.+?):
```

or leave it as it is:

```
(.+?:)
```

The `()` captures whatever is inside.

Comment: works perfect but i need double quotes for apple. the output should be ["{apple}","{mango}","apple:", "apple:","{pear}" ]

Comment: edited the question for missing : after second apple

Comment: The replacement string just needed to be updated to `'"$1"'`.

Answer (score 0):

If *tect* means a key in array-like presentation:

```
$string = '["{apple}","{mango}","[apple: red]", "[apple: green]","{pear}" ]';

$string = preg_replace("/\[(\w+?\:) \w+?\]/","$1" , $string);

// $string now contains  "["{apple}","{mango}","apple:", "apple:","{pear}" ]"
```